# Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to add a new row to my database . Here is my code :

ds1 is my Dataset , da1 is my data adapter

```
        dRow = ds1.Tables["localitati"].NewRow();
        dRow[1] = aux1.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        dRow[2] = aux2.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
        dRow[3] = aux1;
        dRow[4] = e.X;
        dRow[5] = e.Y;
        ds1.Tables["localitati"].Rows.Add(dRow);

        da1.Update(ds1, "localitati");
```

at the `da1.update(ds1,"localitati");` the program stops and gives me the error : "`Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows`."

The connection to the database works ( i have retrieved info from the db )

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define an InsertCommand for you DataAdapter

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/relationaladonet.aspx

Comment: i've also found this http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/insertcommand-sqlserver.htm for anyone else who is interested

Comment: There is no point in using a DataAdapter in that case. It's a pure example about what isn't right to do. Unparametrized query, useless DataAdapter, unclosed connection, string initialization with null - all things that shouldn't exist in a project.

Answer (score 12):

For adding DataRows:

```
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

// add rows to dataset

builder.GetInsertCommand();

//Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
adapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Explanation:

`adapter.Update(dataset)` will try to save the changes in the `dataset` to the database. It will need:

1. **InsertCommand** (if `DataRows` were added)
2. **DeleteCommand** (if `DataRows` were deleted)
3. **UpdateCommand** (if `DataRows` were modified)

You can put a breakpoint to inspect your `adapter.InsertCommand` before the `adapter.Update()` line to see if it is set.

To set them, simply create a `SqlCommandBuilder` and fire `GetInsertCommand()`, `GetDeleteCommand()`, etc.

This should solve the errors:

1. "Update requires a valid Update Command when passed DataRow collection with modified rows." Or
2. "Update requires a valid Insert Command when passed DataRow collection with new rows.", etc.

See [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for More Info

Answer (score 8):

Quesion Solved;Your question:

```
dRow = ds1.Tables["localitati"].NewRow();
dRow[1] = aux1.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").ToLower();
dRow[2] = aux2.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
dRow[3] = aux1;
dRow[4] = e.X;
dRow[5] = e.Y;
ds1.Tables["localitati"].Rows.Add(dRow);

da1.Update(ds1, "localitati");
```

Answer:

you must use commandBuilder.  That is before your update using dataAdapter (or before you creating dataRow)  Add the code:

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dRow = ds1.Tables["localitati"].NewRow();
        dRow[1] = aux1.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        dRow[2] = aux2.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
        dRow[3] = aux1;
        dRow[4] = e.X;
        dRow[5] = e.Y;
        ds1.Tables["localitati"].Rows.Add(dRow);
        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);//just add this line
        da1.Update(ds1, "localitati");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).